# Waiting for "finally" clause in PromiseKit to finish

Tags: ios, promise, promisekit

Currently I am using PromiseKit to chain a logic, which is like the following:

```
[NSURLConnection promise:rq1].then(^(id data1) {
    return [NSURLConnection promise:rq2];
}).then(^(id data2) {
    return [NSURLConnection promise:rq3];
}).then(^(id data3) {
    return [self promiseToDoSomeWorkOnData:data3];
}).finally(^{
    [self cleanup];
});
```

The problem that I am facing is that the method I call in the `finally` clause is asynchronous, but I have no way to chain the `finally` method together with the other promises so that any usage of the whole piece of code somewhere else waits also for the `finally` clause to finish before continuing to a next promise.

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't just change `cleanup` to return a promise, just like you did with `promiseToDoSomeWorkOnData`? Most asynchronous methods offer some completion handler logic, which you can marry with `promiseWithResolverBlock`.

Comment: The reason behind using `finally` is that I want the code executed even if some of the `then` clauses fails.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there should be some rendition of finally that lets you return a promise (though, admittedly, it's going to make the promises and then/finally clauses a little more difficult to follow).